# Conflicts when merging multiple pull request

Tags: git

I am getting something I don't understand now.
I am working on a project with 4 members with bitbucket. Unfortunately, our project management is not that good right now, so if each of us makes pull requests and when we merge it to master in order, conflicts happen in the next pull request since we are working on the same file. But the funny thing is that sometimes some of the pull requests don't have any conflict while others have. All of them are working on a same file. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow 3 simple rules to avoid falling into merge conflicts:

- Keep changes small.
- Git Rebase (or Merge, if you prefer it) with your main branch (ex: master) before git push.

  ```
  git checkout master
  git fetch
  git pull --rebase origin master
  git checkout -
  git rebase master
  ```
- Following a workflow keep things tidy when working with large team. Do checkout this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts does not automatically occur just because you are all working on the same file.

Conflicts happen because you change the same lines in those files, or make changes very close to each other, so that git cannot safely separate them when merging.

If, for instance, one developer makes changes to the top of the file, and another to the bottom, no conflict should occur unless the file is really short.

If you are constantly fighting over the same lines of code in your project, consider restructuring the code, if possible, to avoid this.